# UIActionSheet is taking longer to load

Tags: iphone

are their any reasons why my UIActionSheet would be taking a while to load. It works fine just after lauch, but as soon as I loop through some actions once or twice, is loads very slow, and you can see the grey backdrop crawl down to finish drawing the sheet.

help?

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution moments later.
I assume this is how it works, feel free to correct me. 
U used the cheats animation way of [ UIView ]
and i guess this changed the way for the UIActionSheet to pop up, so I wrote in these two lines before i asked it to show.in.view

```
 - (IBAction)goToBlog{

contactUs.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
[UIActionSheet setAnimationDelay:0];
[UIActionSheet setAnimationDuration:0.1];
[contactUs showInView:self.view];



}
```

and that seemed to work. so im happy.